# Controlling the Position of some items whilst the remainder can be sorted

Tags: javascript, php, silverstripe

I have a `ModelAdmin` with `MyDataObject` has_many `AnotherDataObject` and [SilverStripe Grid Field Extensions Module](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions) that is controlling the

```
class TestAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    static $managed_models = array('MyDataObject');
    static $url_segment = 'testadmin';
    static $menu_title = 'TestAdmin';
}

class MyDataObject extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array('Name' => 'Varchar(255)');
    private static $has_many= array('AnotherDataObjects' => 'AnotherDataObject');

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        if ($grid = $fields->dataFieldByName('AnotherDataObjects')) {
            $grid->getConfig()
                ->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter')
                ->addComponent(new GridFieldOrderableRows('Priority'));

            $fields->removeByName('AnotherDataObjects');
            $fields->insertAfter($grid,'Name');
        }

        return $fields;
    }
}

class AnotherDataObject extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Name'      => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Type'      => "Enum('Middle,Top,End','Middle')",
        'Priority'  => 'Int'
    );
    private static $has_one = array('MyDataObject' => 'MyDataObject');

    function onBeforeWrite() {
        parent::onBeforeWrite();

        if($this->Type == 'Top')
            $this->Priority = DB::query("SELECT MIN(Priority) FROM Type = 'Top'")->value();

        if($this->Type == 'End')
            $this->Priority = DB::query("SELECT MAX(Priority) FROM AnotherDataObjectWHERE Type = 'End'")->value() + 1;
    }
}
```

I'd like to use `Type` on `AnotherDataObject` to control the sort order so that the Top items remain at the top and then End at the end.  I think the easit way would be to prevent the ability to "drap" or "drop" into those positions and control the Priority for the Top/End items within `onBeforeWrite`... but I'm not sure how to disable those from being "drag/drop"... or if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override jQuery UI sortable initialisation:

```
$(".ss-gridfield-orderable tbody").entwine({
    onadd: function() {
        // skipped code

        // the `cancel` option allows to exclude items from drag&drop sorting
        this.sortable({
                handle: ".handle",
                helper: helper,
                opacity: .7,
                update: update,
                cancel: ".ui-state-nosort"
            });
        },
    });
```

You will need to add new class '.ui-state-nosort' to the rows that you want to exclude from sorting.